# How to check if Redis in nodejs app is working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, redis

I installed redis and mongodb in VM, I'm trying to speed the response time of my mongoose find() requests .. I used lean() and it's working good .. then I found redis and I installed it and I followed this tutorial to set up redis in my controllers :
https://epsagon.com/development/using-redis-to-optimize-mongodb-queries/

I created the cache.js in /services with connection details and then in my controller code I imported :

```
const { clearKey } = require("../services/cache");
```

And in my find() I added .cache() :

```
await Book.find({ author: req.query.author }).cache();
```

I want to know how the app is knowing the .cache() function is my redis server because I only imported "clearKey " and I didn't use it ? And the performance is not speeded so I don't know if the Redis set up is correct and working or not.  How to check that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You added the cache function to `mongoose.Query.prototype.cache`, it means that you extended `mongoose.Query` with cache function and it was automatically added to **all** Mongoose models.

Regarding your second question, you need to add to your Redis:

```
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: keys.redisHost, // make sure its your redis host
  port: keys.redisPort, // make sure its your redis port
  retry_strategy: () => 1000
});
```

When your query is running over MongoDB you should see a log:

```
console.log("Response from MongoDB");
```

And when your query is running over Redis you should see a different log:

```
console.log("Response from Redis");
```

You can see more the this github [file](https://github.com/haimrait/node-redis-mongo/blob/master/services/cache.js).